# Pygame game crashes when trying to close the app

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

So im just following a simple Pygame tutorial on youtube and it should work but for some reason every time i try to close the app it crashes and doesn't close normally, here's the code:

```
import pygame

# Initialize the pygame
pygame.init()

# Create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

# Title and Icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")
icon = pygame.image.load('ufo.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# Run game until x is pressed
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

im using the latest version of pycharm and python.

Comment: add `pygame.quit()` at the end of the code

Comment: @Rabbid76 Ofcourse lmao, thanks that fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `pygame.display.quit()` at the last line, you need to tell it to close the window.